# how can i solve problem of raspberry pi window starting?

Tags: windows

I am start raspberry pi window all the operation of initialization of command are completed but start window not display... So how can I do for getting starting window. only blank screen which is display here.. so i do not type any commend here.

Comment: Enter login details, default user name is pi, default password is raspberry. Enter startx and that will load the desktop. Then in Raspi-Config there is  a setting which will set your Pi to automatically boot into the desktop.

Comment: Can you please attach a photo of the screen and indicate which lights on the Pi are on/flashing?